# Move array with same value inside the same array

Tags: php, arrays, merge, grouping

This is my array.

```
Array
(
    [id] => 1
    [color] => "White"
    [something] => Array
    (
        [country] => "France"
        [city] => "Paris"
    )

)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [color] => "Black"
    [something] => Array
    (
        [country] => "Germany"
        [city] => "Berlin"
    )

)
Array
(
    [id] => 2
    [color] => "Red"
    [something] => Array
    (
        [country] => "Russia"
        [city] => "Moscow"
    )

)
```

I want to group arrays with same `id` value. This should be the output:

```
[0] => Array
(
    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 1
        [color] => "White"
        [something] => Array
        (
                [country] => "France"
                [city] => "Paris"
        )

    )

)
[1] => Array
(

    [0] => Array
    (
        [id] => 2
        [color] => "Black"
        [something] => Array
        (
            [country] => "Germany"
            [city] => "Berlin"
        )

    )
    [1] => Array
    (

        [id] => 2
        [color] => "Red"
        [something] => Array
        (
            [country] => "Russia"
            [city] => "Moscow"
        )

    )

)
```

I tried with tens of `foreach` statements but there's no way for me to get arrays with same `id` inside the same array. Is it probably related with the fact that it's a multidimensional array? Should I use 2 nested `foreach` to get the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
<?php

$arr = array(
    array(
        'id'    => 1,
        'color' => 'white',
        'something' => array(
            'country' => 'France',
            'city'    => 'Paris',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 2,
        'color' => 'Black',
        'something' => array(
            'country' => 'Germany',
            'city'    => 'Berlin',
        ),
    ),
    array(
        'id'    => 2,
        'color' => 'Red',
        'something' => array(
            'country' => 'Russia',
            'city'    => 'Moscow',
        ),
    ),
);


function groupify($arr) {
    $new = array();
    foreach ($arr as $item) {
        if (!isset($new[$item['id']])) {
            $new[$item['id']] = array();
        }
        $new[$item['id']][] = $item;
    }
    return $new;
}

print_r(groupify($arr));
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 1
                    [color] => white
                    [something] => Array
                        (
                            [country] => France
                            [city] => Paris
                        )

                )

        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [color] => Black
                    [something] => Array
                        (
                            [country] => Germany
                            [city] => Berlin
                        )

                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [id] => 2
                    [color] => Red
                    [something] => Array
                        (
                            [country] => Russia
                            [city] => Moscow
                        )

                )

        )

)
```

if you don't want to preserve keys, just call `array_values` before `return`.

Comment: Basically i was trying with tens of similar functions with no success. Thanks to your "Result" example i understand where the problem was. I was not passing result inside an Array(). I was always passing 3 separate arrays Array(1) Array(2) Array(3) instead of Array( Array(1) Array(2) Array(3) ). Thank you CertaiN.

Answer (score 1):

Use id for key of new array.

`$a[$array[id]][] = $array;`

Answer (score 0):

If you wanted to use a foreach:

```
<?php
$return = array();
foreach($array as $key => $innerArray) {
    $return[$innerArray['id']][]= $innerArray;
}
```

Now $return contains them groped by ID, where keys 1 and 2 are your IDs

```
array(
    1 => array(
        array(/** **/) 
    ),
    2 => array(
        array(/** **/),
        array(/** **/) 
    );
);
```

You can then access your groups like this:

```
foreach($return as $key => $groupArray) {
    // you have the groups here

    foreach($groupArray as $id => $singleArray) {
       // singleArray contains your id, colour etc
    }
}

foreach($return[1] as $groupOne) {
    // all arrays with id = 1
}
```

Comment: Yes, i was using the same approach but all i get is many buggy arrays (there's some strange logic) but most important all elements with same ID always stay in their own array. Basically [0] => (mess), [1] => (mess), [2] = (mess). I still have 3 keys.

Comment: Sorry. I got it. Your code is working but it's not what i was looking for. Sadly i did a mistake posting my "i want this output" part.